# Active Android crashing on Lollipop not in kitkat

Tags: android, activeandroid

I got a NoClassDefFoundError on Running the app in lollipop device.But in kitkat version,the application working fine.

I have pointed out the error line in below code.

**StackTrace:**

```
07-31 02:48:23.337  13673-13673/com.ms.ha E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ms.ha, PID: 13673
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
            at com.activeandroid.ReflectionUtils.getModelClasses(ReflectionUtils.java:83)
            at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.activeandroid.Registry.openDatabase(Registry.java:149)
            at com.activeandroid.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:107)
            at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:8)
            at com.ms.ha.fragment.HomeFirstFragment.onCreateView(HomeFirstFragment.java:73)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5948)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**HomeFirstFragment.java:**

```
public class HomeFirstFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener {


    SharedPreferences prefdatabase;
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.ms.ha/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "appdb";
    SharedPreferences.Editor eDIT;
    private String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/AndroidApp";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmetn_home, container, false);


        if (file.exists())
        {
            try {

                ActiveAndroid.initialize(getActivity()); ----> Error line
                initializeDatabase();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            eDIT.putString("Value","true");
            eDIT.commit();
        } else {
            System.out.println("2ND");
            try {

                eDIT.putString("Value","true");
                eDIT.commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
 }
```

**Manifest:**

```
 <application
        android:name="com.ms.ha.activity.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_114x114"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  .....
  .....


  <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="appdb" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="1" />

  </application>
```

**Application.java:**

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

  public Application() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize the Parse SDK.

    Parse.initialize(this, "", "");

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();


  }
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/activeandroid-3.0.jar')     

}
```

I am not sure why it is working in kitkat version not in lollipop version.I have updated the appcompat lib to 22.But still error occurred at runtime.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. But I download the beta version and build it. Everything worked fine. 
Download beta version 3.1 from [here](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/downloads).

Comment: I have had several mistakes with lollipop, I've solved updating the library to fork dreipol, which will have fixed many bugs https://github.com/dreipol/ActiveAndroid

Answer (score 1):

check if you had installed your application on Lollipop before, so you have to use migration .sql file in assetets or delete all application data on the device then install new application version.